# Term for $P(Z > z)$?

Tags: probability-distributions

I know that $P(Z \leq z)$ is considered the CDF of the random variable $Z$ but is there a term for $P(Z > z)$?

For example, if $Z \sim \mathrm{Exp}[\lambda]$, what is $P(Z>z)$?

Comment: This is sometimes called the [survival function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_function).

Comment: @Ian Perfect! Thank you :)

Comment: Reliability function, among others.

Answer (score 1):

As for all $z \in \mathbb{R}$

$$
P(Z \leq z)+P(Z>z)=1
$$

you could call $P(Z>z)$ the "1-complement of the CDF".

Comment: Okay, thank you! I just wanted to see if there was a specific term